# When I popToRootViewController, none of the views on the stack between the current VC and the root VC get their deinit called

Tags: swift

For example here is the problem I'm facing; I have 3 view controllers. When I'm on VC1, the memory is at 9.2MB, when i go to VC2, the memory is at 50MB, and it jumps to ~52MB when I go to VC3.

VC1 -> VC2 -> VC3.

When I get to VC3, I popToRootVC to VC1. But VC2 does not have its deinit called, so when I'm on VC1 (the root view controller), the memory still hovers around 48MB.

What I have tried is, before I popToRootVC, I send a notification to VC2 to remove all of the views I have added to the superview, set these respective objects to nil, clear any arrays, set optional variables I have to nil and then finally removing VC2 as an observer to the notification default centre.

The problem is the memory still hovers around ~48MB, I'm not sure what's causing this problem or how to solve it.

Any idea why this is happening and/or suggestions on what I can do in order to narrow down a solution?

Comment: There must be s reference to the vc held somewhere, maybe a reference loop, that prevents its destruction

Comment: @Feldur what is the best method to go about finding what is holding the reference to the VC?

Comment: Don't know I can suggest a good way. I usually study the code looking for where the reference has been passed. Closures and delegates are common ways of making reference loops, which is all it takes.

Comment: @Feldur fair enough. For UICollectioniviewcells / UITableViewCells, do I need to make delegates weak? Also for an IBOutlet, do I need to set the delegates to nil as well?

Comment: @Feldur I realized that my collectionviewcells were holding a strong reference back to the UICollectionView, so now that I changed my protocols to abide by the "class" keyword, now there is no strong reference! thank you so much!! The problem I'm facing now, is that the memory is still high, despite the deinit of VC2...any clue on why this might be happening?

Comment: I'd probably have to see the application. You could try using instruments to see if that helps you visualize where it's going. There are some good tutorials on the net that if you're not familiar with how to use it would give you the basics.